# Switching order of composition of functions

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

I'm stuck on a matter related to my research.

Are there any results done on when one order of composition of functions is bigger than another? More specifically, for which functions f and g does

f(g(x)) > g(f(x))?

Are there any specific classes of functions for which this holds?

The functions I'm considering are also convex and non-decreasing if that is relevant. Thanks.

Comment: I am also interested in that question. Why do you want this ?
See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/323326/switching-the-order-of-composition-of-two-functions

Answer (score 0):

Square root and exponential are two such functions.
√ (e^x)  > e ^ √x

For x>4.